# Palavra quebrar linha na coluna do Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Estou tentando fazer uma quebra de linha em um span ou em qualquer outra tag.

A ideia é que se o usuário digitar apenas uma palavra e ocupar mais espaço que a coluna, essa palavra quebre pra próxima linha.

Abaixo um exemplo do que está acontecendo utilizando o span, se eu tenho uma palavra muito grande não quebra a linha e ultrapassa a coluna:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Exemplo</title>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="col-4">           <span>TesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTe steTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTeste</span>
      </div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Alguém sabe alguma solução?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Então Julio, neste caso podemos utilizar a propriedade e valor: `word-wrap: break-word;`, junto na sua classe que o span irá utilizar.

Essa propriedade irá fazer a quebra de linha em seu texto.

Por exemplo:

```
CSS
 span {
  word-wrap: break-word
 }

HTML 
<div class="col-4">           
     <span>TesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTe steTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTesteTeste</span>
</div>
```